# d3 - xScale not updating?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I'm trying to make a d3 scatterplot with two drop-down menus. The drop-down menus are used to select which datasets to plot against each other. I use two global variables to keep track of which datasets are currently used. "currentX" is the name of the first dataset (on the x-axis) and "currentY" is the name of the second dataset.

My scale functions depend on the values of "currentX" and "currentY". Here is an example of my xScale function:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d){return d.data[currentX]}), d3.max(dataset, function(d){return d.data[currentX]})
.range([padding, w - padding])
.nice();
```

My yScale function is the same, but uses currentY instead of currentX. My problem is that when I try to change views of the data, my scale doesn't update. Here is the code for changing between views of the data:

```
d3.selectAll('select')
.on('change', function() {

// Update currentX and currentY with the currently selected datasets
key = Object.keys(dataset[0].data)[this.selectedIndex];
if (this.getAttribute('id') == 'xSelect') {currentX = key}
if (this.getAttribute('id') == 'ySelect') {currentY = key}

// Change data used in the scatterplot
svg.selectAll('circle')
.data(dataset)
.transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d.data[currentX]) })
.attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d.data[currentY]) })
.attr('r', 2)
};
```

I want the xScale and yScale functions to update, to reflect the new values of currentX and currentY. But for some reason, these functions are not updating. If anyone could help me fix this, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

---

UPDATE: Just to clarify, my problem is that my xScale and yScale functions do not change, even though xCurrent and yCurrent (and their minimum and maximum values) have changed. For example, "console.log(xScale(-5))" always produces the same value. This value should change as xCurrent and yCurrent change! Thanks again.

---

UPDATE 2: The global variables "xCurrent" and "yCurrent" ARE being updated. Furthermore, if I define NEW xScale and yScale functions in the .on('change') function, then my scales are updated. This actually fixes my problem, but I would still like to know why I can't do it the other way. Still trying to learn D3!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the x scale domain inside your change function. Also, you can use `d3.extent` instead of `d3.min` and `d3.max`. For example:

```
.on('change', function () {
  // Update currentX and currentY with the currently selected datasets
  key = Object.keys(dataset[0].data)[this.selectedIndex];
  if (this.getAttribute('id') == 'xSelect') {currentX = key}
  if (this.getAttribute('id') == 'ySelect') {currentY = key}

  xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d){return d.data[currentX];}));

  // Change data used in the scatterplot
  svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataset)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d.data[currentX]) })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d.data[currentY]) })
    .attr('r', 2)
})
```

This is because the scale generator isn't aware of changes to your data. It's `domain` method isn't going to be called every time the data changes. Thus, when the data does change, you have to explicitly set the scale's domain before re-drawing any data that depends on it.